# cin and cout redeclaration

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have doubt in my mind regarding declaration of cin and cout object . As per my understanding cin and cout both object are accessible in main then they shouldn't have protected.in below code snippet i have overloaded both input and output operator and
    while giving new name (ofstream obj) to user defined version of this operator , I am getting error like obj is protected and can't be accessed here. Anybody can suggest .

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class overload
{
public:
    int var_a;
    overload (int fun_a=10): var_a(fun_a)  {}
    friend ostream operator >> (ostream &output, overload &);
    friend istream operator << (istream &input, overload &);
};

ostream &operator <<( ostream &output, overload &s1)
{
    output<<"value of object output:"<<s1.var_a<<endl;
    return output;
}

istream &operator >>( istream &input, overload &s1)
{
    input >> s1.var_a;
    return input;
}

int main()
{
    overload s1,s2;
    //ostream obj;
    //obj<<"enter the value of object"
    cout<<"enter the value of object";
    cin>>s2;
    cout<<s2;

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: If you want to output to the screen, why would you just not use `std::cout`, like you have in your example? What are you trying to do with `std::ostream obj`? Where do you want it to "go"?

Comment: You seem to be confused about what are objects and what are functions. `ostream obj;` tries to default construct an object of type `ostream` and this is likely giving you the error you're talking about. `operator>>` is a function, you don't "give it a name", but call it with arguments, like `cout` and `s2`, for example.

Comment: i ran this code in g++ and it is giving output

Comment: Your friend declarations don't exactly match your actual functions.

Comment: @aschepler: Missing a `&` seems a recurring problem.

Comment: Guys , I do understand that by the below code snippet it is possible to do this job.  ostream obj(cout.rdbuf());

    obj << "Hello, world!\n";  .  but my question is if istream and ostream doesn't allow the object declaration due to protected inheritance then why still cin and cout are accessible in main function.  Why this protected inheritance comes here in picture still i can invoke them accessing via friend function as per shared example.

Answer (score 0):

The relevant part is the & in `ostream &`. That makes it a reference.

In your `main()`, you can in fact do the same: `ostream& obj = std::cout;`. Just like the `ostream& output` in `operator<<` is valid while that function runs, `ostream& obj` will be valid while the `main` function runs.

[edit]
As for your comment, that's missing a critical point. `std::cout` is an `std::ostream`, yes. But `std::ofstream` (file) also is an `std::ostream`. Wait, you may say, one type is another type? Yes, in OO languages. Inheritance means that each object has the type used to construct it, but also any base types inherited from.

That's why you can pass a file stream to your `operator<<` overload. The `std::ostream&` can be initialized with any derived object.

Comment: Good Answer. In c++11 compiler, After compilation of commented code,i am getting below error :

c:\mingw\include\c++\4.9.0\ostream:384:7: error: 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::basic_ostream() [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]' is protected
       basic_ostream()

if i haven't mistaken then constructor of ostream class seems to be protected and below code snippet also indicates that still by using reference it can be made possible because it ignores straight away construction .

ostream& obj= std::cout;

obj<<"Hello World";

Comment: @user2907032: It doesn't really "ignore" construction, it merely references an already constructed object (`std::cout` to be precise.)

Comment: Thanks Msalters for your comment.   i am curious to know by seeing the error message, what is the reason behind to make this classes (istream and ostream) protected.Still I am able to acees this object in main or friend function with reference.

Comment: @user2907032: They're base classes. They're the common parts of e.g. `ofstream` and `cout`. Those common parts cannot exist in isolation, but they can be _used_ in isolation.